# Missing MSVCR71.dll error on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, dll

I work with a Windows 8.1(x64). I am a Python student and today I tried to install the pyTTS by UNC Assistive Technology. But, when i tried to install it, the system gave me the error listed in the title of my post above.
I tried to install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336) but nothings changed.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure the version of the file goes to C++ 2008 redistributiable and not an even earlier version?  Be sure you are installing both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions

Comment: [Possible fix here](https://community.extremenetworks.com/extreme/topics/cannot-launch-airranger-on-win-8-1-msvcr71-dll-is-missing) Different software but fix should work for any program that throws this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to wikipedia MS Visual Studio 2003 equals version 7.1.
<s>Install the 2003 ~~redistrutable package.</s>

EDIT: There is no 2003 Redistrutable. According to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596167/where-to-download-microsoft-visual-c-2003-redistributable), the runtime is included in .Net 1.1.

Comment: there is no 2003 redist. The applications have to include it.

Comment: Or you can install the NET 1.1 runtime, as I've read. I edited my answer accordingly -thanks for the heads-up.